# Can Maui configure a shadow in a line?

Tags: xaml, shadow, maui, .net-maui

I´m developing an app in .net maui and i have a question i have not answered myself through browsing.
I'm trying to apply a shadow to a border and the following code works perfectly.

```
   <Border 
    Style="{StaticResource light-theme-border}"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="3"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="7">
    <Border.Shadow>
        <Shadow 
                Brush="red"
                Offset="1,11"
                Radius="20"
                Opacity="0.25"/>
    </Border.Shadow>
   </Border>
```

But when i write shadow directly inside the border properties it catches the property but i don't know how to dump the [brush, offset, radius & opacity] info:

```
    <Border 
        Style="{StaticResource light-theme-border}"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
        Shadow="???????????????????????????">
    </Border>
```

Comment: What it is the problem with the first code ?

Comment: I want to attach the property "shadow" to my style sheet to re-use the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can then define and consume it as a resource (same what you did with `Style` property):

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Shadow
                x:Key="CommonShadow"
                Brush="red"
                Offset="1,11"
                Radius="20"
                Opacity="0.25"/>
    <Border 
        Style="{StaticResource light-theme-border}"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
        Shadow="{StaticResource CommonShadow}">
    </Border>
```

Or integrate it in your existing style of `Border`

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="light-theme-border" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Shadow">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Shadow
                            Brush="red"
                            Opacity="1"
                            Radius="50"
                            Offset="20,20" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
    <Border 
        Style="{StaticResource light-theme-border}"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="7">
    </Border>
```

Or integrate it in your existing style of `Border` as a static resource

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
             <Shadow
                x:Key="CommonShadow"
                Brush="red"
                Offset="1,11"
                Radius="20"
                Opacity="0.25"/>

            <Style x:Key="light-theme-border" TargetType="Border">
                  <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="20" />
                  <Setter Property="Shadow" Value="{StaticResource CommonShadow}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

    <Border 
        Style="{StaticResource light-theme-border}"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="7">
    </Border>
```

Comment: This is all i needed. now i have the same shadow available for all my borders. Thank you so much

Comment: Cool, you're welcome you can also integrate it in your existing style if it is more convenient to you as in the edit i made to my answer